# How to get group of checkboxes values in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have a group of check boxes which has same name,it is as follows

```
one row has

      1.checkbox
      2.text box1
      3.text box2
```

i want to get the check box value which is selected as well the text boxes values which are in the row that the checkbox exist.

UPDATE :

```
S.No    Header Name     Size    Display Order
1        checkbox        25          1
2        checkbox        25          2
3        checkbox        25          3
4        checkbox        25          4
```

This is how my html page looks like, suppose if `s.no 1 selected means i want to get the SIZE and DISPLAY ORDER` values which are in text box.

this is the code i used but did not even goes in :

```
function customiseReport()
        {
           alert("customiseReport : ");
           var oParent = document.getElementById('headername');
           var aElements = oParent.getElementsByTagName('input');
           for (var i = 0; i < aElements.length; i++) {
              if (aElements[i].type == 'checkbox' && aElements[i].checked==true) {

              }
           }
        }
```

how to do this in javascript?

Please help.

Regards

Comment: see my update,this how the html page looks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <div id="checkbox_list">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes"/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes"/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes"/>
    </div>
    <button id="btn_clickme">Click me</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#btn_clickme').click(function () {
                alert('number of selected checkboxes: ' + $('.checkboxes:checked').size());
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i want the values of selected checkbox as well inputs values of the corresponding checkboxes